# A question about the well-ordering theorem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In Munkres' book "Topology", he states that

> Well-Ordering Theorem: If $A$ is a set, there exists an order relation on $A$ that is a well-ordering.

Then, in his discussion of the Maximum Principle, he writes that

> For a given uncountable set $A$, we know from the well-ordering theorem that there is a bijection between $A$ and some well-ordered set $J$ so that we can index the elements of $A$ with the elements of $J$, i.e. $A = \{a_\alpha : \alpha \in J\}$

My understanding of the Well-ordering theorem is that for a **given** set $A$, we can put a well-ordering on this set, so is the set $J$ that Munkres refers to actually the set $A$ itself and the bijective map is the identity map
$f(\alpha) = \alpha$ for $\alpha \in A$?

Can this set $J$ be something different?

Comment: I think you could assume that, yes. We could assume $J$ is a cardinal in its standard ordinal well-order, if you know some set theory.  Then the same index set is "canonical" in a way, and the same one could be used for many sets. But taking the identity and using the promised well-order from the first theorem would work too.

Comment: I see. But, from the first theorem alone, is there a way to show existene of some bijective map from the set $A$ to some well-ordered set $J$, which is not equal to the set $A$ itself?

Comment: Munkres didn't write that we can take $A$ as $J$. Why? I think he is a very kind writer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$J$ can be anything that has the same cardinality with $A$.

For example, you can index $\{k\in\Bbb N\mid k\text{ is even}\}$ using the natural numbers, $\{2n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$; or using the odd natural numbers, $\{k-1\mid k\in\Bbb N, k \text{ is odd}\}$; or using any other countable set.

Comment: How do I know that a set with the same cardinality with A  exists?

Comment: Well, $\{A\}\times A$ have the same cardinality as $A$. And assuming the usual axioms of set theory, $\{A\}\times A\cap A=\varnothing$.